# How can I get around Grub?

Tags: grubrescue

My ubuntu partition on the hard disk drive is lost. The Cmos/Bios has been locked by a password.  The 'Is' command is not recognised by grub. Please help me!!!

Comment: Computers shouldn't just all of a sudden have a BIOS password appear. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You must clear the unknown Cmos/Bios password and reinstall Ubuntu from live-usb.

On the motherboard locate the BIOS clear jumperand change its position.

This jumper is often labeled Clear, Clear Cmos, CLR, CLRPWD.

To clear, remove the jumper from the two pins currently covers the replace it over the other two.

Once the appropriate jumper or dips switch has been located and toggled, the password should be cleared.

Turn your machine on to verify that the password has bee reset.

Once cleared, turn the computer off and return the jumper or dip switch to its original position.

If your computer is a laptop and you are the original owner of the laptop, we highly recommend contacting the manufacturer of the laptop. Companies can reset the password if you are the original owner.